# Fetching rows from two sql tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables `RecordMaster` and `Dummy`

Both have columns like `Mobile_Number` and `Insert_Date`

I want a row like

1) from `Dummy` table I want to fetch those rows whose `Mobile_Number` And `Insert_Date` are same   compared to `RecordMaster`.

2) from `Dummy` table I want to fetch those rows whose `Mobile_Number` And `Insert_Date` are different compared to `RecordMaster`.

After that in 1) condition I want to fetch only those rows whose `Cpv_Status` is not null.
`(CPV_STATUS)` is one column in the `Dummy` table..

Help me please ........

Comment: Do you want to fetch rows from `Dummy` such that **any** row from `RecordMaster` matches (by `Mobile_Number` and `Insert_Date`)? Or do you actually want to JOIN these two tables by some kind of `ID` that you have now shown us and then return only those that **also** match by `Mobile_Number` and `Insert_Date`?

Answer (score 1):

1. To meet your 1) and 3) needs ( optionally include the `WHERE` as you need).

```
SELECT d.* 
FROM Dummy d 
INNER JOIN RecordMaster r 
   ON r.mobile_number = d.mobile_number
   AND r.insert_date = d.insert_date
WHERE d.Cpv_Status IS NOT NULL
```

2.

```
SELECT d.* 
FROM Dummy d
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT 1 
     FROM RecordMaster r 
     WHERE r.mobile_number = d.mobile_number
     AND r.insert_date = d.insert_date
    )
```

To insert these:

```
INSERT INTO RecordMaster(mobile_number, insert_date)
  SELECT d.mobile_number, insert_date 
  FROM Dummy d
  WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT 1 
     FROM RecordMaster r 
     WHERE r.mobile_number = d.mobile_number
     AND r.insert_date = d.insert_date
    )
```

Comment: @Vivek: it's exactly what you wanted. Get the dummy records where they match against RM. Note `SELECT d.*`

Comment: It does NOT "copy records" from RM. It simply ensures that the same 2 values exist on another row in RM.

Comment: Okay Got it.. Thanx man !!! i also want to insert all records into RecordMaster which satisfied my 2) condition !!!

Comment: @Vivek be sure to mark the answer that helped you the most with the green checkmark. It's part of the question-and-answer system, as well as the reputation system on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

The following query will give you all records in dummy that match the records in RecordMaster

```
SELECT a.Mobile_Number,a.Insert_Date ,a.Cpv_Status
FROM RecordMaster a, Dummy b
WHERE a.Mobile_Number = b.Mobile_Number and a.Insert_Date = b.Insert_Date
```

The following query will give you records in Dummy that don't have matching records in RecordMadter

```
SELECT a.Mobile_Number,a.Insert_Date ,a.Cpv_Status
FROM Dummy a
WHERE STR(a.Mobile_Number)+STR(a.Mobile_Number) not in 
(SELECT STR(Mobile_Number)+STR(Insert_Date) FROM RecordMaster)
```

if you need both of these results combined in one result set, then use UNION like this

```
SELECT a.Mobile_Number,a.Insert_Date ,a.Cpv_Status
FROM RecordMaster a, Dummy b
WHERE a.Mobile_Number = b.Mobile_Number and a.Insert_Date = b.Insert_Date

UNION

SELECT a.Mobile_Number,a.Insert_Date ,a.Cpv_Status
FROM Dummy a
WHERE STR(a.Mobile_Number)+STR(a.Mobile_Number) not in 
(SELECT STR(Mobile_Number)+STR(Insert_Date) FROM RecordMaster)
```

Lastly, you can apply any filter you want to the final result set like this:

```
select * from (

SELECT a.Mobile_Number,a.Insert_Date , a.Cpv_Status,a.Cpv_Status
FROM RecordMaster a, Dummy b
WHERE a.Mobile_Number = b.Mobile_Number and a.Insert_Date = b.Insert_Date

UNION

SELECT a.Mobile_Number,a.Insert_Date ,a.Cpv_Status
FROM Dummy a
WHERE STR(a.Mobile_Number)+STR(a.Mobile_Number) not in 
(SELECT STR(Mobile_Number)+STR(Insert_Date) FROM RecordMaster)

) where Cpv_Status is not null
```

Comment: You'll need a table alias on your derived table if you want to apply any WHERE clause. The third example will not execute; syntax error. Overall a suboptimal set of SQL queries if we're being honest: old style / improper joins, along with an index-wasting string concatenation in the where clause. There's no reason to join 2 columns together (twice!) when it can be done properly.